# Accessing array elements within a vectorized function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to write a function which computes the Simpson integral for given inputs. Parts of these inputs can be in the form of a `float` or `np.array`.

Currently, my function is as follows:

```
s = np.array([0.2,0.3,0.4])

@np.vectorize
def recovery(s,R0,n):

    x = np.linspace(s,1,n)
    y = 1/(x*R0(x))
    ans = simp(y,x)

    return ans
```

This works fine and returns:

```
array([a, b, c]) ## Where a, b and c are the correct answers
```

However if I only want to access the first element in the array within the function, by:

```
return ans[0]
```

I get the error message:

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable
```

I also get all different kinds of errors when trying to play around with the output "ans", e.g.:

```
return type(ans)
ValueError: invalid __array_struct__

return len(ans)
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

The aim of the function is to return a `float` if the input `s` is a float, or an `array` if the `s` input is an `np.ndarray`.

I'm a complete python beginner so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *“This works fine and returns”* — please add an example how you called that function and what you obtained. Numbers, not a, b, c.

Comment: Also what is `simp`? Please make your examples self-contained.

Comment: `np.vectorize` isn't a good function for this or for a beginner.  It doesn't help with speed, and is tricky to use right.

Answer (score 1):

To access only the first element of the return array, you need to do so outside the function, not inside, because inside the function `ans` is still a scalar.

So while

```
return ans[0]
```

doesn't work,

```
recovery(s,R0,n)[0]
```

or

```
ans = recovery(s,R0,n)
ans[0]
```

will work.

The confusing thing here is that the decorator `@np.vectorize` changes the function from one that maps scalars to scalars to one that maps vectors to vectors. But this manipulation is being done "outside" the function `recovery`; inside the original source code of the function, everything is as if it's still a function on scalars.

That's why when you wrote `return ans[0]`, Python complained that you were trying to index a scalar; *inside the function*, `ans` is a scalar.